# Is there a maven plugin that will generate RequestFactory EntityProxy classes from my domain classes?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, maven, requestfactory

I am looking for a maven plugin that will auto generate EntityProxy interfaces from my domain classes.

The class could implement the various interfaces to be generated and then each field or accessor method could use an annotation.

```
public class MyDomainObject implements MyDOProxyFoo, MyDOProxyBar {

    @ExposedBy({MyDOProxyFoo.class})
    public String foo;

    @ExposedBy({MyDOProxyBar.class})
    public String bar;

    @ExposedBy({MyDOProxyFoo.class,MyDOProxyBar.class})
    public String foobar;

    ...
}
```

Then the getters/setters for the respective fields would be in the respective generated interfaces.

You could do something like a readonly attribute in the annotation to only expose a getter in the specified interfaces.

```
...
@ExposedBy({MyDOProxyBar.class}, readOnly = {MyDOProxyFoo.class})
public String bar;
...
```

I could run something like

```
mvn rfproxygen:generateproxies
```

and I would have all my proxy interfaces nicely created in the generated sources directory.

I guess the argument is deciding wether you should have service data binding logic in your domain model.

Comment: Are you looking for a plugin or do you want to write one? Your question looks more like suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a maven plugin that is capable of generating proxies but there is an [issue addressing this for GWTP](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/issues/detail?id=349&q=generate&colspec=ID%20Stars%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Component%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary). Maybe this will of interests for you if it's finished.